# How to fill in observations for years with no data when surveys taken periodically

Tags: stata

My data looks like this

```
tertiaryeduc    avgeduc
.05               .71
.                 .
.                 .
.                 .
.                 .
.07               .871
.                 .
.                 .
.                 .
.                 .
.11               1.137
.                 .
.                 .
.                 .
.                 . 
.15               1.378 
.                 .
.                 .
.                 .
.                 .
```

Though I'd like to fill in the years with no data with the previous known value, so it looks like this

```
tertiaryeduc    avgeduc
.05               .71
.05               .71
.05               .71
.05               .71
.05               .71
.07               .871
.07               .871
.07               .871
.07               .871
.07               .871
```

What are the commands for this?

Comment: Google FAQ replacing missing values Stata

Comment: You shpuld at least try some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As flagged in comments, this is an [FAQ](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/replacing-missing-values/).

Presumably there is a structure here of distinct identifiers, which should be explicit and respected.

```
clear 
input tertiaryeduc    avgeduc
.05               .71
.                 .
.                 .
.                 .
.                 .
.07               .871
.                 .
.                 .
.                 .
.                 .
.11               1.137
.                 .
.                 .
.                 .
.                 . 
.15               1.378 
.                 .
.                 .
.                 .
.                 .
end 

gen id = sum(tertiaryeduc < .)

bysort id : replace tertiaryeduc = tertiaryeduc[_n-1] if missing(tertiaryeduc)

list, sepby(id)
     +-------------------------+
     | tertia~c   avgeduc   id |
     |-------------------------|
  1. |      .05       .71    1 |
  2. |      .05         .    1 |
  3. |      .05         .    1 |
  4. |      .05         .    1 |
  5. |      .05         .    1 |
     |-------------------------|
  6. |      .07      .871    2 |
  7. |      .07         .    2 |
  8. |      .07         .    2 |
  9. |      .07         .    2 |
 10. |      .07         .    2 |
     |-------------------------|
 11. |      .11     1.137    3 |
 12. |      .11         .    3 |
 13. |      .11         .    3 |
 14. |      .11         .    3 |
 15. |      .11         .    3 |
     |-------------------------|
 16. |      .15     1.378    4 |
 17. |      .15         .    4 |
 18. |      .15         .    4 |
 19. |      .15         .    4 |
 20. |      .15         .    4 |
     +-------------------------+
```